# If var condition to redirect to url

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use the jQuery version of the mobile redirect script provided here - http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

The simple instruction says, "jQuery.browser.mobile will be true if the browser is a mobile device"

I am trting to create a if condition to redirect the page but I am a newbie. Help would be appreciated.

```
var mobile = "jQuery.browser.mobile";
var url = "http//domain.com/mobile";

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (mobile = true) {
        $(location).attr('http://domain.com/mobile',url);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just remove the quotation around `jQuery.browser.mobile` on the first line. it should work

Answer (score 2):

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile) {
    location.href = 'http://domain.com/mobile';
}
```

However, you **need to learn JavaScript first**. The code you posted clearly shows that you do not understand the basics of the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mobile = true) {
```

should be

```
if (mobile == true) {
```

or better yet,

```
if (mobile) {
```